# Gatsby unable to create static pages for all the database items

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have been trying out the tutorial Gatsby and MongoDB: https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/gatsby-modern-blog

Everything works fine until adding the file `gatsby-node.js`. Ideally, upon adding this file, it should generate the pages for 400 odd books from the database, but it isn't.

There isn't any error with the code. Am I missing anything?

Any help would be appreciated.

book.js (The template for creating the pages)

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "./layout"

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const book = this.props.data.mongodbGatsbyBooks

    return (
      <Layout>
        <div>
          <img src={book.thumbnailUrl} alt={book.title} />
          <h1>{book.title}</h1>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default Item

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    mongodbGatsbyBooks(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      title
      longDescription
      thumbnailUrl
      isbn
      pageCount
      publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
      authors
      categories
    }
  }
```

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const { data } = await graphql(`
    {
      books: allMongodbGatsbyBooks {
        edges {
          node {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const pageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/components/book.js')

  for (const { node } of data.books.edges) {
    createPage({
      path: '/book/${node.id}/',
      component: pageTemplate,
      context: {
        id: node.id,
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `mongodbGatsbyBooks` vs `allMongodbGatsbyBooks`

Comment: I guess you are pointing out that both the databases are different.

```mongodbGatsbyBooks``` : Db for each individual book's attributes.

```allMongodbGatsbyBooks``` : Db having the id of all the books.

There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: one of them gives empty set ? - use `graphiql` to check if data is available and how - or `console.log(data)` in node or `props.data` in component?

Comment: Neither of them is empty. I have just verified it.

Comment: anything logged? `console.log(node)` in loop? `gatsby clean` to clear cache ?

Comment: ```console.log(node)``` has given the ids of all the items in allMongodbGatsbyBooks. 

I've tried ```gatsby clean``` multiple times, it hasn't helped.

Comment: `book` is rendered? `console.log(this.props.data)` before `return (`

Comment: It hasn't printed anything in the terminal when I used ```console.log(this.props.data)```

Comment: hmmm ... "During development, or when adding new plugins to the options, don't forget to call

yarn clean" ?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I tried everything suggested by you and both the GraphQL queries are working perfectly. I suspect there's some issue with the JS code I've posted above. Do you mind checking it?

Comment: I have resolved the issue and it was a very minor one. In the part ```path: '/book/${node.id}/'```, I used single quotation mark instead of  `

Comment: copy/paste better :D